# What's the reason behind the 787 and 777's "thicker" engine nacelle?

Tags: jet-engine

If you look at images of the 777 and 787 engines (both RR & GE), such as these pics
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/B787-2139.jpg/220px-B787-2139.jpg

https://www.ainonline.com/sites/default/files/uploads/2016/04/genxenginecopy.jpg

And here's the 777X:

https://media.bizj.us/view/img/11591269/boeing-777x-first-flight-weather-cancelled-11*1200xx5066-2850-0-222.jpg

You'll notice the forward grey part of the nacelle appears "thicker" than seen on other aircraft, here's an A350 engine for example:
https://www.aerospace-technology.com/wp-content/uploads/static-progressive/Airbus%20A380%20TrentXWB.jpg

The grey part of the engine doesn't appear to be painted as "thick" as with the 777 and 787. Same with all other Airbus/Boeing planes, except the two highlighted ones.

Anyone know why this is? I don't think it's necessarily about just engine size either, as the TXWB is bigger than both the engines on the 787, but the grey part isn't as thick.

Comment: The cowl is normally designed by the airplane manufacturer or a contracted 3rd party, not the engine maker. The forward silver part gets quite hot when the cowl anti-ice is on. A particular designer elected to use unpainted metal behind the leading edge on that one cowling design. Why? You'd have to ask Boeing.